# How to write neat and clean code in React componentWillReceiveProps method with using nextProps Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({executor : nextProps.executor, wife : nextProps.wife});

  // Some filtering and functional Operation on nextProps value of wife and executor.
}
```

I want to optimise the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const {executor, wife} = nextProps;
  this.setState({executor, wife});

  // Some filtering and functional Operation on nextProps value of wife and executor.
}
```

this way you can optimize and use the variable like wife without any changing the value.

Answer (score 1):

If `nextProps` has only two objects `executor` and `wife` you can set it in one line

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState(nextProps,()=>{
    // Your callback after it sets the state
    // Some filtering and functional Operation on nextProps value of wife and executor.
  });
}
```

Or go with the way as @Harsh answered by defining a constant

```
const {executor, wife} = nextProps;
this.setState({executor, wife});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use the new **getDerivedStateFromProps**.

Use the new *getDerivedStateFromProps* method to do the same if you are using React 16 as `componentWill***` methods are being deprecated now. Also, please note that it's a **static** method. Read more about this new method [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return {
      props.executor,
      props.wife
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 destruction, also added default object value to be safe.

```
componentWillReceiveProps({executor, wife} = {}) {
   this.setState({executor, wife});
}
```